# Filter users after the role

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am very beginner in Laravel.

I have this code:

```
    class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
    {
        use Notifiable;

        public static $roles = [];


        protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'enable', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'email_verified_at', 'password', 'counter', 'url_address',  'isCompany', 'isMailing', 'content', 'nip1', 'business1', 'phone1', 'street1', 'number1', 'postal_code1', 'city1', 'country_id1', 'provincial_id1', 'nip2', 'business2', 'phone2', 'street2', 'number2', 'postal_code2', 'city2', 'country_id2', 'provincial_id2', 'nip3', 'business3', 'phone3', 'street3', 'number3', 'postal_code3', 'city3', 'country_id3', 'provincial_id3', 'cash', 'lng', 'lat', 'enable_map', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'last_login_at', 'last_login_ip' ];


        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];


        public function roles()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
        }

        public function mainRole()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
        }




        public function hasRole(array $roles)
        {

            foreach($roles as $role)
            {

                if(isset(self::$roles[$role]))
                {
                    if(self::$roles[$role])  return true;

                }
                else
                {
                    self::$roles[$role] = $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->exists();
                    if(self::$roles[$role]) return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }

    }
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('enable')->default(0);
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('surname', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 120)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->bigInteger('counter')->default(0);
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->boolean('isCompany')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('isMailing')->default(0);
            $table->text('content')->nullable();
            $table->string('nip1', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('business1', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('phone1', 60)->nullable();
            $table->string('street1', 150)->nullable();
            $table->string('number1', 8)->nullable();
            $table->string('postal_code1', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('city1', 100)->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('country_id1')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('provincial_id1')->default(0);
            $table->string('nip2', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('business2', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('phone2', 60)->nullable();
            $table->string('street2', 150)->nullable();
            $table->string('number2', 8)->nullable();
            $table->string('postal_code2', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('city2', 100)->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('country_id2')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('provincial_id2')->default(0);
            $table->string('nip3', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('business3', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('phone3', 60)->nullable();
            $table->string('street3', 150)->nullable();
            $table->string('number3', 8)->nullable();
            $table->string('postal_code3', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('city3', 100)->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('country_id3')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('provincial_id3')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('cash', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('lng', 10, 8)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('lat', 10, 8)->default(0);
            $table->boolean('enable_map')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        });



Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        });


Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        });
```

and seed:

```
public function run()
    {
        DB::table('roles')->insert([
            'name' => 'admin'
        ]);
        DB::table('roles')->insert([
            'name' => 'adminCompany'
        ]);


        DB::table('roles')->insert([
            'name' => 'receptionist'
        ]);

        DB::table('roles')->insert([
            'name' => 'user'
        ]);

    }
```

I would like to display a list of users who have the ADMIN role.

I have this code:

```
public function showAdminList(string $query, string $sortColumn, string $sortMethod) {

    return User::where('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('surname', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orderBy($sortColumn, $sortMethod)->paginate(25);

}
```

The above code shows me all the users I have in the database. How can I display only those users who have the ADMIN role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scope in your User class, something like this:

```
public function scopeIsAdmin($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
        $q->where('name', "ADMIN");
    });
}
```

Then you can add it to your query like so:

User::isAdmin();

You will have to make sure that you include your OR statements correctly:

```
   return User::isAdmin()
        ->where(function ($q) use ($query, $sortColumn, $sortMethod) {
            $q->where('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('surname', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orderBy($sortColumn, $sortMethod)->paginate(25);
        })->paginate(25);
```

I have not tested the above code so you may need to alter it slightly.

In response to your second question, you can probably use a different scope:

```
public function scopeOfRoleType($query, $types)
{
    return $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($types) {
        $q->whereIn('name', $types);
    });
}
```

and then do User::ofRoleType(['admin', 'receptionist])....

Comment: it's not working. I have error: Cannot use variable $sortColumn twice

Comment: It's working. Thank you. I have second question. If I want to display 2 roles: admin and receptionist - how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [querying relations in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) for "Querying Relationship Existence".

In your case, your `User` model has many-to-many `roles` relationship. If you want to select only those users who has certain role, you can query `users` like this:

```
$role = 'receptionist';
$receptionists = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($role) {
    $query->where('name', $role);
})->get();
```

So just add this `whereHas()` call to your query and read `$role` value from your request.

Comment: This is not working :( I have error: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

Comment: @trafficker the query I gave you was just an example. In your case you are using `->paginate()` to retrieve results, not `->get()`. Change it to `->paginate()`